# MWAA - environments constantly loading

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I'm currently trying to set up an Airflow environment via MWAA. I've gone through the create environment steps twice with both ending at the page listing Airflow environments with a banner saying I was successful. However, for the past 2 days, this environments page has just shown `Loading Environments`, as shown below. I also see a (0) for the environment number.

[image: loadingpage]

So far, I've added 2 interfaces for ECR and VPC for the API and the environment but no luck. Has anyone else run into this issue or have any clue what might be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to find the solution to this issue? I had similar issues when I tried to set up the first-time MWAA on AWS Account.
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/MWAA
Here's a link to how to verify if all the resources are set up correctly for MWAA. If you run the script mentioned on the repo you should be able to see where the issue lies.

Comment: This is not an answer to the problem but I guess it helps.

Comment: There's no error message so I can't give the correct answer but what helps me to alleviate issues in the AWS support tools. If you run the verify.py script for MWAA and It will show you If you've set up resources correctly or not. If that script shows no error means there's something wrong with VPC Endpoints.